# C# how to disable webbrowser usage

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# application that has a webbrowser and need to be able to completely disable it at times.  What is the best method of doing this?

I was thinking about creating a transparent panel to put over the webbrowser when needed, but am not sure if this is the best approach.  I also noticed that C# doesn't easily allow making a panel transparent.

Edit:  To clarify what I mean by disable...I don't want to allow the user to be able to click or change\edit anything in the webbrowser.

Comment: You may want to add more relevant tags to this, too; this isn't just a C# question, but a WinForms or WPF question.  You'll get people looking for those kinds of things with the proper tags.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'm new here.  :)

Comment: See my answer below about how completely disabled the control is when you set Enabled to false.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

<strike>Strangely the WebBrowser control doesn't have an Enabled property as you might expect it to. You can set the AllowNavigation property to false which will stop the user clicking on links.</strike>

Turns out it does have an Enabled property, inherited from Control. But you have to explicitly cast it to Control to access it:

```
((Control)webBrowser1).Enabled = false;
```

You should be aware though that setting Enabled *completely* disables any user interaction with the WebBrowser control. That includes the scroll bar, so once you set Enabled to false the user can't even scroll the web page in the control.

If that was more than you wanted then setting the AllowNavigation property to false will stop the user clicking on links but still allow them to scroll the page. You'd need to check though that it also stops Javascript onclick events from firing.

If you wanted to stop any events from firing in the page you could probably achieve that will some DOM work from the WebForms code into the WebBrowser control. You also probably need to start disabling input controls within the WebBrowser. It all depends how disabled you want it.

Comment: Yes it works. But I understand your concern, I don't know why it hides it.

Comment: Why the down vote ? Are you worried that Enabled it hidden for a reason or something else ?

Comment: Couldnt be easier. I just wonder how people find solutions like this.

Comment: @C4u, people find many things by looking at the documentation. The Enabled property is documented for the WebBrowser control but the documentation says it is not supported.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your last comment, I would assume you are using WinForms. (WPF does allow for transparent panels quite easily :-)) This means you are using the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control. Have you tried setting its [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx) property to false?

Comment: Gah, I got downvote because some people don't know they can cast the browser to Control to get to the Enabled property?!

Comment: I suspect that the questioner looked for an Enabled property and the WebBrowser control make a good job of hiding the fact that it has one hidden away. The fact that it hides the Enabled property makes me wonder whether that property actually works in all cases on all OSes.

Comment: It does not show in Intellisense because of a conflict between the Enabled inherited from Control and Enabled inherited from WebBrowserBase. However, the property is documented and downcasting to Control works on all OSes.

Comment: andynormancx's comment above shows how to do this in WinForms.

Comment: @VictorStoddard yes, he does. He edited his answer based on mine. That's not a reason to downvote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'disable' it, what do you mean? If you set the 'Enabled' property to false, it will be disabled, this works for all form controls. But if you needed to, you can set a panel to transparent by setting it's BackColor.

UPDATE:
Actually, you're right, it's an wrapper for an ActiveX control, so it's not a typical WinForms control. What you want is the transparent paenl solution. This guy Tobi has a solution on his blog:

http://saftsack.fs.uni-bayreuth.de/~dun3/archives/creating-a-transparent-panel-in-net/108.html

the basic idea is overriding this method on the panel class:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
         CreateParams createParams = base.CreateParams;
         createParams.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; // WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
         return createParams;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the webbrowser from its parent Control array?

Comment: The question says "disable it at times" implying the ability to enable it later. I have certainly been down voted for "answers" that provided more than is here. Removing the control sounds easy but perhaps some sample code showing how to also add it back at the correct z-order would help, I am not sure how simple that would be.

Answer (score 0):

In VB:  DirectCast(WebBrowser1, Control).Enabled = False